# Android how to share an image with some text?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-sharing

On [Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) they described how to share multiple images, but what I wanna do is share a screenshot and a link to the app, I am able to take screenshot and share it without any problem, but when it comes to adding text, it doesn't work, a toast message appear that says sharing failed, and it appears that it's from receiver side like facebook or whatsapp, can i do this or not?

Comment: Can you post your code.?

Comment: I don't have code other than posted in link I've attached

Comment: Can you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814268/android-share-on-facebook-twitter-mail-ecc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read that question : [Android share text and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326313/android-share-text-and-image) - I hope it will be helpful for you, it is answering your question in general (OP has very similar problem)

Comment: it doesnt throw toast message anymore, but also shares nothing!