# Share Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, image, android-intent, share

I would love to share a picture with a text or url. 
I'm using this code but I am only sharing the image, and changing the order of the "type" makes me share both but only as email / gmail 
What am I doing wrong?  my code is:

**edit1**

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
           share.setType("*/*");
           share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,               Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Wallpaper/1.jpg"));
           share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "helloworld");
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, (getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.condividi))));
```

Comment: In the question you mentioned ACTION_SEND i.e. you want to send single file but in your code you want to send multiple files and providing only single URI. What you wanna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
File DoutFile = new File(path);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(DoutFile));
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "" + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify MIME type also for the text. `"text/plain"` is the type of text data MIME. Try using `"*/*"` as MIME, so you can send any generic data type.

Also try changing `ACTION_SEND` to **ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE** which specialized for delivering multiple data.

More info about ACTION_SEND_MULTPLE and handling MIME types:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: if I try to share it on facebook or whatsapp me appears a toast "attach only one photo or video"

Comment: see, your problem have been solved. you can share one file with text now with this code. what more do you require?

Comment: what exactly do you require? you need to send a picture with text right? is not that happening now? :)

Comment: for sending multiple files you can use an array list and make a loop and send them one by one, do not forget to up-vote and accept the answer if it helped. :) cheers

Comment: does not share anything I want to accept your answer but I did not understand what to do

Comment: Check this link out. it will show you why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076717/android-share-intent-for-facebook

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send multiple files then use the following code :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Add any subject");
intent.setType("image/*"); /* sharing any type of image. Modify to your need */

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(String path : filesToSend /* List of images you want to send */) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files); /* adding files to intent */
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have to use filesToSend as a variable?

Comment: **filesToSend ** is string array which has paths of all your images like `http://url of image/ab.png`, `http://url of image/abc.png`, `http://url of image/abcd.png`, etc.

Comment: but the image is already on the phone and the path is predefined by me

Comment: @GappAiello First of all you want to send single file or multiple files? Your question's title and posted code is confusing me.

Comment: i want to send the image of the path "file :/ / / sdcard/Wallpaper/1.jpg" with a text

Comment: try this in `..EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("file :/ / / sdcard/Wallpaper/1.jpg"))` instead of `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,               Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Wallpaper/1.jpg"));`

Comment: @GappAiello also replace `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` with `ACTION_SEND` in your code (do both suggestions in your code not mine).

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6814268/1979347 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14326313/1979347 and also whatsapp don't allow sharing both image and data at the same time see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15526495/1979347

Comment: friend there are applications that do this with whatsapp and facebook